# How to add text below image in CardView

Tags: android

I want to add some text after an image inside a card view. 
This is the XML layout I have written:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_main"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/main_img"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:text="Hello World"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Here text is not shown below the image. Only image and white space are shown. How to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
android:textColor="@color/white"
```

And I believe you use white background

> white space are shown